# Phpspec return bad value

Tags: symfony, phpspec

I created register service and I want test that method. In the browser var_dump return true and phpspec return false.. Why ? Any Ideas?

Service : http://pastebin.com/9hYX7S14
Phpspec : http://pastebin.com/xm5NLYyG

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stub (or mock) all your dependencies:

```
    function it_check_user_exist_in_system(
        Registry $doctrine, 
        ObjectRepository $repository,
        User $user
    )
    {
        $doctrine->getManager()->willReturn($doctrine);
        $doctrine->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:User')->willReturn($repository)

        $repository->findOneBy(array('username'=>'user1'))->willReturn($user);

        $this->checkUser('user1')->shouldReturn(true);
    }
```

Comment: If repository found user1 return true, but  if repository not found user2 return true.. what's wrong ?

Comment: In that case:

        function it_returns_false_if_user_not_found(
            Registry $doctrine, 
            ObjectRepository $repository
        )
        {
           $doctrine->getManager()->willReturn($doctrine);
           $doctrine->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:User')->willReturn($repository)
     
         $repository->findOneBy(array('username'=>'user1'))->willReturn(null);
     
            $this->checkUser('user1')->shouldReturn(false);
        }

Comment: Thanks bro. Works :) I forget about willReturn(null) ; :)

Comment: If my answer was helpful please select it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok.  Last question. I try test peresit layer, whether my service save user. Spec give me 100%  but with error  Call to undefined method Prophecy\Prophecy\MethodProphecy::persist()
Me test is correct or fail why? 
  http://pastebin.com/ua87hRJK

Comment: getManager should return a manager not a Registry: $doctrine->getManager()->willReturn($entityManager); and then $entityManager->persist($site)->shouldBeCalled(); and same for persist.

Comment: I can't see that option.. ;/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the result from a Mocked object.

You're best bet for testing this method is to test using a should be called assertion on the mocked object.

This is not a unit test its functional/acceptance test.

Comment: Why isn't a unit test?  It's part of service, so should be unit.

Comment: Here your SUS is ``RegisterTest`` class, you are testing it's behavious therefore you have to ``simulate`` it's collaborators. If you need to test a service, then it's not a unit test, as nathanmac said, it would be a functional/acceptance and I would suggest using Behat for that.